# jquery Slide effect on multiple DIVs with embedded close effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many questions here so please be patient with me, very new jquery/javascript user.

Here is my current page http://integratedcx.com/index.php/experience

Basically I would like each of the projects and project categories to have the hidden div, slidedown like a drawer not just appear as they do now.

I have tried to achieve this through jquery without much success, here is my working http://integratedcx.com/temp/slide.html

1. How do I get the div below the one opening to "ease" down instead of jump
2. How do I get my close feature (orange box) in recent projects to work properly
3. How do I get my the project list on the right side of image to hide (as it does on my current page) as well as have the drawer opening effect.
4. Is there an easy way to i.e. variable to assign this to multiple divs using jquery.

Thank you in advanced for any/all help.

Comment: My question on 4. is how do I apply the script over multiple divs, ie projectx becomes project1, project2, project3, how do I make x a variable in my script.

Answer (score 1):

For your question 4, With the following script (based on [ComputerArts's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12945868/43452) above), you can easily add the slide effect to a large number of divs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle-to-show").click(function (evt) {

      var targetdiv = $(evt.currentTarget).attr("data-drawer");

      $(targetdiv).slideToggle(1000, function() {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $('.bracket', evt.currentTarget).html('less');
                $('.project', evt.currentTarget).hide();
                $('.closebox', this).bind('click', function(e) {$(evt.currentTarget).triggerHandler('click');});
            }
            else {
                 $('.bracket', evt.currentTarget).html('more');
                 $('.project', evt.currentTarget).show();
                 $('.closebox', this).unbind('click');
            }
      });
   })

})
```

Then, you can mark up the toggle buttons and sliders as follows:

```
<div class="toggle-to-show" data-drawer="#firstsection">
     <div class="project">Project One Heading</div>
     <div class="bracket">more</div>
</div>

<div id="firstsection">
     <h3>Project One Heading</h3>
     stuff
     <img class="closebox" src="close.jpg">
</div>

<div class="toggle-to-show" data-drawer="#secondsection">
     <div class="project">Project Two Heading</div>
     <div class="bracket">more</div>
</div>

<div id="secondsection">
     <h3>Project Two Heading</h3>
     stuff
     <img class="closebox" src="close.jpg">
</div>


<div class="toggle-to-show" data-drawer="#thirdsection">
     <div class="project">Project Third Heading</div>
     <div class="bracket">more</div>
</div>

<div id="thirdsection">
     <h3>Project Three Heading</h3>
     stuff
     <img class="closebox" src="close.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

   ```
   $("#link_id").click(function(){
     $("#div_to_show").slideDown();
   });
   ```
2. http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

   ```
   $('#div_to_close').slideUp();
   ```
3. Using both of the methods from 1, and 2
4. By using class names instead of IDs for your selectors. For example:

   ```
   $(".link_class").click(function(){
     $(this).parentsUntil('.ex-wrapper').find('.div_to_show').slideDown();
   });
   ```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I wouldn't suggest using animate since the height will surely be dynamic. Using a slide function would be more appropriate.

Comment: Good idea... I will change to slideDown

Answer (score 0):

As for points #1 and #2, [try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMjxL/) 
I only changed the first script tag to

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".projectx-show").click(function () {
        $("#projectx").slideToggle(1000, function() {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
              $('#projectx-bracket').html('less');
            }
            else {
              $('#projectx-bracket').html('more');
            }
        });
    })

})

</script>
```

FYI, you don't need to use `$(window).load` and then `$(document).ready`... one is enough

As for #3, I don't understand what you're trying to say.

#4, yes there is a way, using classes and keeping the structure the same for every bloc in your page.

Comment: For his #3 look at the "completed projects" section of the old site. The headings disappear from the right, and appear in the slide-out.

Comment: @Stobor Thanks I get it now! Was far away from what I was thinking

Comment: I like the use of slidetoggle, is it possible to have the last line of paragraph show first with slidetoggle as it does now on the working page?

Comment: @ComputerArts Thank you for the help. Regarding note 3. how do I modify your fiddle so that <ul class="project"> hides onclick. Regarding note 4. if I do not have some sort of variable for x, it will apply the effect to the first "#projectx" in my code.

Comment: Can I add some sort of $(this).next("#projectx")

Comment: Here's a hint on 4: http://jsfiddle.net/kMjxL/1/ - look for "toggle-to-show" "data-drawer" "bracket" and "closebox" throughout the html.

Comment: @Stobor Thank you for the fiddle, works great. I will review your note 4 hint, thank you so much for the direction.

Comment: @Stobor and ComputerArts Thank you both for your help, this will work great.